# display custom p-values with facet wrap ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a faceted ggplot which displays counts for multiple binary variables. I would now like to display post-hoc chi square comparisons for the frequency counts on each graph.

Below is some (made-up) data representing my design

```
condition <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
binary_1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
binary_2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
binary_3 <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
binary_4 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(condition, binary_1, binary_2, binary_3, binary_4)
```

I can generate the global chi square test using `CrossTable(df$condition, df$binary_1, chisq = TRUE, digits = 2, sresid = TRUE, expected = TRUE)`

The post hoc chi square tests are calculated using the following function from the old fifer package

```
chisq.post.hoc <- function(tbl,test=c("fisher.test"), popsInRows=TRUE,control=c("fdr","BH","BY","bonferroni","holm","hochberg","hommel"),digits=4, ...) {
  #### extract correction method
  control <- match.arg(control)
  
  #### extract which test (fisher or chi square) 
  test = match.fun(test)
  
  #### test rows or columns
  if (!popsInRows) tbl <- t(tbl)
  popsNames <- rownames(tbl)
  
  #### come up with all possible comparisons
  prs <- combn(1:nrow(tbl),2)
  
  #### preallocate  
  tests <- ncol(prs)
  pvals <- numeric(tests)
  lbls <- character(tests)
  for (i in 1:tests) {
    pvals[i] <- test(tbl[prs[,i],], ...)$p.value
    lbls[i] <- paste(popsNames[prs[,i]],collapse=" vs. ")
  }
  adj.pvals <- p.adjust(pvals,method=control)
  cat("Adjusted p-values used the",control,"method.\n\n")
  data.frame(comparison=lbls,raw.p=round(pvals,digits),p.value=round(adj.pvals,digits))
}
```

Using this function results in output (for a single variable in the faceted graph) like in the following table:

```
matrix_1 <- as.matrix(table(df$condition, df$binary_1))

table_1 <- chisq.post.hoc(matrix_1, test='chisq.test')
table_1
```

[image: post hoc chi square p-values]

Below is the syntax for my faceted graph

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggsignif)
require(ggpubr)


gg_df <- df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("binary"), as.factor))

gg_melt <- tidyr::pivot_longer(gg_df, -condition, names_to = "binary")

ggplot(gg_melt, aes(x=condition, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDAE61", "#9E0142"), name = "Behaviour Observed", labels = c("0" = "Absent", "1" = "Present")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(a = "Condition A", b = "Condition B", c = "Condition C")) + 
  xlab("Condition") + 
  ylab("Number of Participants") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~binary)
```

[image: Graph Generated by above syntax]

I would like to display the graphs as follows, where the p-values represent those in the table above for each variable/facet. Ideally I would also like to only display significant comparisons (this is made up data with very few samples so none of these post-hoc tests are significant unfortunately). Is there a way to do this using ggsignif? This thread [Add P values to comparisons within groups boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198635/add-p-values-to-comparisons-within-groups-boxplot) is the closet I have found, but I am having trouble applying the suggestions given there because the function is different, and my data is transformed into long format for faceting.

thanks in advance!

[image]