# display significance for multiple t-tests/comparisons in one graph ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to create a graph which displays the values for 3 separate t-tests for different outcomes. I am trying to use the stat_compare_means function from ggpubr, but keep receiving the following error: `` Computation failed in `stat_signif()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed ``. This is the same error as [Add P values to comparisons within groups boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198635/add-p-values-to-comparisons-within-groups-boxplot) but my case is much simpler. Is there a way to fix this?

Example code below

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr)

condition <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
outcome_1 <- c(5,4,4,3,5,2,3,4,5,3)
outcome_2 <- c(4,3,3,2,5,4,5,3,2,4)
outcome_3 <- c(1,2,3,3,2,4,4,5,1,2)

df <- data.frame(condition, outcome_1, outcome_2, outcome_3)

df_means <- df %>%
  select(condition, outcome_1, outcome_2, outcome_3)

gg_means <- melt(df_means, id = "condition")

#dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.5)

ggplot(gg_means, aes(x = reorder(variable, -value), y = value, fill = factor(condition))) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.75) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey70", position=position_dodge(width = 0.8), width =.25) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group=condition), 
                     label = "p.signif", 
                     method="t.test", 
                     comparisons = (list(c("a", "b")))) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,5,by = 1), limits = c(0,5), expand = c(0,0))
```

Below is a picture of the output:

[image: Here is a picture of the output]

Basically, I want to display the t-test p-value (ideally actually a mann-whitney U test) for each outcome between conditions a and b.

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I suspect the problem is related to `comparisons` where "a" and "b" are provided, but your x-axis is `variable`, so the comparisons it is looking for would be something like your outcomes, or an index (1, 2, or 3 for outcomes 1, 2, and 3). Try just removing `comparisons...` from your `stat_compare_means`...and add `label.y = 4.5` so your results will be visible. This seems like it would provide the appropriate grouping for comparisons...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I edited the code so that the stat_compare_means syntax looks like ` stat_compare_means(aes(group=condition), 
                     label = "p.signif", 
                     method="t.test",
                     label.y = 4.5) + ` and it no longer displays the `Computation failed in stat_signif(): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` error, but it is still not showing the p values.

Comment: Does it show `NS` for not significant?

Comment: Try `p.format` instead of `p.signif`

Comment: ah yes, I just saw that it does. Is there a way to display the exact values?

Comment: that worked! thank you so much! :)